# Why am I unable to run yo angular successfully?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am running a `windows 8.1 64-bit` machine.

`Node` and `npm` were installed.(latest versions `0.12.x` and `2.7.x`)

Installed `YO BOWER GRUNT-CLI GULP GENERATOR-ANGULAR` correctly.

Now when I run "yo angular", the project files are being generated and `bower install` and npm install` are running. Till now its fine.

`bower install` goes well. But `npm install` stuck in middle and gives different ERR (sample - `ERR registry parsing json sometimes different`) and finally it freezes executing `phantomjs.exe` forever. If I quit that `cmd prompt` and run grunt in that folder, it says `grunt not installed`.

This happened every time I run this. Tried almost all googled suggestions. One more thing is that I cannot delete that folders created by yo angular.

Kindly help me run it completely